# When I use Super+Prt Scr I get a transparent file

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, screenshot, transparency

I am using Gnome 3.12.2

This is a screenshot taken when I press <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> (I have a dual screen. Chrome is maximised).

[image]

This is one is taken when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (My shortcut to take an area screenshot).

[image]

This is what happenes when I do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>

[image]

It varies though. Sometimes it it completely white or black or transparent. Google chrome and terminal are completely black, Inkscape is yellow, and . The white space on that one atually has random transparent marks on it:

(Screenshot of image viewer display)

[image]

I also have a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> to take a screenshot of a window and copy it to the clipboard.

That produced the same as above.

Finally, a screenshot of my list of Screenshot shortcuts, taken with area shot.

[image]

I'm using `NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.117 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)`

Comment: Are you using a graphics driver of some sort?

Comment: Yep, `NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.117 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)`

Comment: That might be a problem: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684620

Comment: Thank you! Switching to 331.38 to try it! Add it as an answer and you'll get some rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684620), this bug shows up when NVidia driver v304 is installed. Upgrading to a higher version ought to solve it. The bug report states that v319 is known to fix it, at least. On Arch Linux, I have v340 installed and the bug hasn't shown up.

Comment: You get the up-vote, but it hasn't solved it yet.. Do i need to restart / restart `lightdm`?

Comment: @Tim You might have to restart Ubuntu itself to get the new module working properly, I suppose. At any rate, that's what I doing whenever I upgrade the graphics card driver. Or you could restart gnome-shell - press Alt-F2, and try the `r` command.

Comment: Yeah, I'll turn it off tonight and check tomorrow :)