# Is there a way to get a list of all folders on a harddrive with the amount of used space?

Tags: files, disk-usage

Somehow my harddrive is full and I can't find the source, so is there a way to get a list of all folders on a harddrive with the amount of used space?
I could do it manually and check the properties of each folder, but this would be too much work.

I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Be careful removing stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to search the dash for either `baobab` or `Disk Usage Analyser`. This is already installed.

You can either chose doughnut or box graph, click the buttons in the bottom right to switch.

Doughnut:

[image]

Grid:

[image]

Hover over to view the size... (3GB here)

[image]

... and click on a folder to see what makes that up:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, I wonder if they were full-desktop screenshots later cropped (as opposed to per-window screenshots taken using `Alt+PrtScn`)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503889/when-i-use-superprt-scr-i-get-a-transparent-file Well noticed! Very annoying. Some are full screen cropped (number 3, to show the hover box)  but the others are Area screenshots...

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Disk Usage Analyser app (installed in Ubuntu by default).

Comment: How can I open this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command line if you would rather.

```
ls -h -l /path/to/folder
```

or

```
ls -sh -S /path/to/folder
```

to show you it ordered by size.

You can choose which folder in your file system to view, and view it in many different ways using this tool. /home is often a big one. There is more info available in the manual:

```
man ls
```

That command will show you all the different options. Cheers!

Comment: Cool - how can I sort the output?

Comment: @Tim that would be `ls -sh -S` (the `-S` flag sorts by size).

Comment: Note that this won't show the size of directories (as most people understand it) - it'll show the size used by the directory **metadata** (the representation of the directory on the filesystem internals). To calculate the (usual) size, you'd use `du -hs`